# Does kerberos support a grace period in password changes?

Tags: passwords, kerberos

The principles are programs instead of human. I want to rotate their password regularly, using random generated password, and then deliver the new password to the programs. I have a mechanism to make program use the new password at its next kerberos connect, but the delivery may take time.

I am concerned that the principle would fail to authenticate using the old password right after I change the password, but before I deliver the new one.

Is there some mechanism in kerberos to prevent this? Like kerberos remembering the last password and accept both the old and new password for a period of time?

I'm currently using MIT kerberos, but can switch to other implementation if that can meet my requirement.

Comment: I think that this would not be a feature of the Kerbros protocol itself but rather of a specific implementation. So you might rather want to ask if the Kerberos authentication server you use supports this.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks, I've added the additional information about implementation.

Comment: For humans, many see regularly changing passwords as no longer good advice (providing the ones they have are "sufficiently good"), and the same might apply to programs instead of people. However, even if you don't change them automatically, there may be occasions when you _do_ need to change them, so handling the overlap between changing the password and telling the program the new password would still need to be handled.

Comment: There is a [description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/11/13/to-kvno-or-not-to-kvno-what-is-the-version/) regarding how windows active directory deal with this situation. Seems the kvno field may take care of this situation, and mit kerberos has an option named [keepold](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/database.html)

Comment: Strictly speaking the protocol itself does not. In fact it will explicitly fail in this scenario because it can't agree on the right keys.